# cx_freeze incompatible with python 3.2

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I was trying to install cx_freeze for Python 3.2, and I was told by multiple other questions and even the cx_freeze website itself that cx_freeze is compatible with Python 3.2, but I can't seem to find the download for it (the only downloads available on PyPI were for Python 3.3 and 3.4). Can someone direct me to where I can get it?

Comment: can you not update to python 3.4? There are downloads here that seem to include python 3.2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/files/.

Comment: If you go back to cx_Freeze 4.3.2 in the Sourceforge files @PadraicCunningham linked to, there's an installer for 3.2. But I'd definitely recommend upgrading Python if possible.